# How to conditionally add dynamics in music function?

Tags: lilypond, lily-scheme

I have a moderately complicated, repetitive section in a piece. Thus, I want to use a shortcut to typeset it all.

However, the dynamic can change. For example, sometimes I will want to attach a \sf, sometimes an \ff, and other times nothing.

This is what I've come up with, but it doesn't work (variables read as `do-sf` and `do-ff`):

```
\version "2.22.1"

dramaticEnding = #(define-music-function
    (dosf doff)
    (boolean? boolean?)
    #{
        c #(cond
            (dosf \sf)
            (doff \ff))
        c
    #})

\relative c'' {
    \dramaticEnding ##t ##f
}
```

In the actual use case, the pitch is also a variable. Of course, I am open to other interfaces, like passing the dynamic as a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things fundamentally wrong here. First defining a new music function uses the command `define-music-function`, not `make-music-function`. Second to access something like `\sf` from within scheme code you need to omit the backslash. (`\value` will try to resolve `value` in the global scheme scope. If this is a music object a copy of that object is returned, if it is a music function it will try to determine the arguments and evaluate it). So you need to do

```
dramaticEnding = #(define-music-function
    (dosf doff)
    (boolean? boolean?)
    #{
        c #(cond
            (dosf sf)
            (doff ff))
        c
    #})
```

or to be on the save side even

```
\version "2.22.1"

dramaticEnding = #(define-music-function
    (dosf doff)
    (boolean? boolean?)
    #{
        c #(cond
            (dosf (ly:music-deep-copy sf))
            (doff (ly:music-deep-copy ff)))
        c
    #})

\relative c'' {
    \dramaticEnding ##t ##f
    \dramaticEnding ##f ##f
}
```

Alternatively you can create a parsing environment by `#{ \sf #}`. This has the advantage that lilypond will automatically be able to attach location information to the event:

```
\version "2.22.1"

dramaticEnding = #(define-music-function
    (dosf doff)
    (boolean? boolean?)
    #{
        c #(cond
            (dosf #{ \sf #})
            (doff #{ \ff #}))
        c
    #})

\relative c'' {
    \dramaticEnding ##t ##f
    \dramaticEnding ##f ##f
}
```

Alternatively though you might want to create the function rather to take hooks for you to specify the dynamics:

```
\version "2.22.1"

dramaticEnding = #(define-music-function
    (dyn1) ; for more places add more arguments
    ((lambda (x) (or (ly:music? x) (not x))))
    #{
        c $(if dyn1 dyn1)
        c
    #})

\relative c'' {
    \dramaticEnding \sf
    \dramaticEnding \ff
    \dramaticEnding ##f
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need! I edited my question to remove my stupid `make-music-function` mistake.

Answer (score 2):

As an "frame challenge", you could also accomplish this by putting the dynamics in their own `Dynamics` context instead of "attaching" the dynamics to the notes.  (See [the last example in the "Dynamics" section of this LilyPond doc page,](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/expressive-marks-attached-to-notes#dynamics) right before "Selected Snippets".)  So something like this should work:

```
repeatednotes= {c4 d e f g a b c}

<<
  \new Staff \relative c'' {
    \repeat unfold 2 {\repeatednotes}
  }
  \new Dynamics {
    s1*2\sf |
    s1*2\ff
 }
>>
```

Comment: Hopefully this is relatively close to functional code;  I don't have LilyPond installed on the computer I'm currently working at.  If there are tweaks needed to make this work, I welcome edits to this answer.

Comment: The code works fine, it's just in a funny octave.

Comment: This could also go as the accepted answer. Very elegant!